# Why this gives 0 in php?

Tags: php, function, logic

```
<?php
  function a($n){
    return ( b($n) * $n);
  }

  function b(&$n){
    ++$n;
  }

  echo a(5);

  ?>
```

I did an exam this sunday and would like to know why the output for this code is **`0`** ?

I'm no developer in php so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When I run it, I get 36

Comment: Can verify, [see the demo](http://codepad.org/E4aIlOOn)

Comment: It will be 0 for a(-1), can't otherwise

Comment: Sorry, I mix with the other code I was working on, the correct one was updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code gives `0` because it is missing a `return`. Compare with the following which (when corrected as shown) produces `36`, as reasoned in the other answer.

```
function a($n){
  // Since b($n) doesn't return a value in the original,
  // then NULL * $n -> 0
  return ( b($n) * $n);
}

function b(&$n){
  // But if we return the value here then it will work
  // (With the initial condition of $n==5, this returns 6 AND
  //  causes the $n variable, which was passed by-reference,
  //  to be assigned 6 such that in the caller 
  //  it is 6 * $n -> 6 * 6 -> 36).
  return ++$n;
}

echo a(5);
```

See [Passing by Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) for how `function b(&$n)` works above; if there signature was `function b($n)` the result would have been 30.

Comment: Why -1? That's correct...The lack of return makes it return `null`. +1

Comment: this is correct. +1. `b` of course changes the value of `$n` but not brings the changed value(coz not returned) which the OP is assuming I assume.

Comment: @Lekhnath The variable is still changed, as per the other answer. This is why the result is 36, not 30.

Comment: @user2864740, thank you! now I got it what was my mistake.

Comment: @ValterHenrique Cool, sometimes it's the simplest things are the easiest to miss.

Answer (score 3):

```
function a($n) {
    return (b($n) * $n);
}

function b(&$n){
    ++$n;
}

echo a(5);
```

This is what happens when you call `echo a(5);` (not in the actual order, it's just for demonstration):

```
return (b($n) * $n);
```

This return statement has two parts: `b($n)` and `$n`. `b($n)` is a call to the function `b`. Function `b` accepts its arguments by reference and increments the value by `1`. Note that **it doesn't return a value**.

Since it doesn't return a value, `b($n)` will be `NULL`. Proof:

```
function a($n){
    $v = b($n);
    var_dump($v);
    return (b($n) * $n);
}
```

Output:

```
NULL
```

In the next step, you multiply the result of `b($n)` (which is `NULL`) with `$n` (which equals to `6`).

So the result is `NULL` * `0`. What's the result? Use `var_dump()`:

```
var_dump(NULL * 6);
```

Output:

```
int(0)
```

Everything will be fine and dandy if you return a value in `b`:

```
function a($n){
    return (b($n) * $n);
}

function b(&$n){
    return ++$n;
}

echo a(5);
```

Output:

```
36
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, in PHP, the return statement is equal to NULL / 0.
So even if, the b() function changes the value of n by reference, the return statement is equal to null.
Then when you multiply this return statement by (equal to zero) by any number, it will equal to zero.

Try to add 'return 1' at the end of the b() definition, the result should be equal to *n*.